# Dynamic Optimization / Dynamic Programming

Tags: macroeconomics

I am now taking a course on Macroeconomic Theory and suffering from a terrible professor who can't teach. So, I am studying by myself. Today, I received a problem set and seriously have no idea
The question is
Consider the following optimal growth model with quadratic utility and full depreciation
$$\sum_{t=0}^\infty = \beta^t(c_t - \frac{a}{2}*c_t^2)$$
subject to the resource constraint $$k_{t+1} = Ak_t - c_t + y_t$$
and k0 is given, Assume that beta is in (0,1); A > 1, yt is a given bounded deterministic labor income process, and a > 0 is set to be a value such that the utility function is always increasing in consumption.

a)
Derive the lifetime resource constraint using (2) and the non- Ponzi game condition. What restriction do we need to impose on the model parameters such that optimal consumption is constant over time.
[image: I computed it like this by just copying the lecture notes]

During the lecture, the processor said when beta*R = 1, the optimal consumption is constant. How should I approach this one?

b)
Assume that yt = y > 0. Formulate this maximization problem as a dynamic programming problem and solve explicitly for the value function and the consumption function.

What I know about DP is that it is another way of solving a dynamic optimization problem. I have to construct the Bellman equation and compute the derivative through the Envelop theorem and find an Euler Equation. Am I understanding it correctly?

It is my first time trying a real problem
Please help me
I would be grateful if you could give me some more intuition
Thank you so much